# TypeScript get Svelte component's prop type

Tags: typescript, svelte

Let's say you are using a component that has been imported from elsewhere

```html
<Animal species={animalSpecies} /> // species has a specific type
```

and you want to pass it a certain variable that you expect from somewhere else:

```html
<script lang="ts">
import Animal from 'animals'
export let animalSpecies : ???
</script>

<Animal species={animalSpecies} />
```

One way to do this would be to go into the source file and find a way to import the type directly. But is it possible to retrieve the type directly from the component?

If there was a way, for example, to get the typeof like:

```
export let animalSpecies : ComponentType<Animal.species>
```

Answer (score 17):

This is also possible using the built-in Svelte types that are available now:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import type { ComponentProps } from 'svelte';
  import Animal from 'animals';
  // The below has the types of all props on the Animal component now
  export type AnimalPropTypes = ComponentProps<Animal>;
</script>
```

Comment: And to get a specific property's type: `ComponentProps<Animal>["species"]`

Answer (score 6):

Anthony's answer didn't work for me – it converted all the props to optional.
Hoewever, I was able to use the following:

```js
import type { SvelteComponentTyped } from "svelte";
export type Props<T> = T extends SvelteComponentTyped<infer P, any, any> ? P : never;

// and a bonus:
export type Events<T> = T extends SvelteComponentTyped<any, infer E, any> ? E : never;
export type Slots<T> = T extends SvelteComponentTyped<any, any, infer S> ? S : never;
```

Answer (score 4):

This works for me

```
// This returns all the component's properties as a Partial: { prop1?: string, ... }
type ComponentProperties<T extends { $set: (...args: any) => any}> = 
  NonNullable<Parameters<T['$set']>[0]>;

// This returns the type of a specific property
type ComponentPropertyType<
  T extends { $set: (...args: any) => any}, 
  P extends keyof ComponentProperties<T>
> = NonNullable<ComponentProperties<T>[P]>;
```

Usage:

```
export let animalSpecies: ComponentPropertyType<Animal, 'species'> = ...;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using generics. This is especially useful if you need Typescript to infer types that come from a library, as you may not want to import or duplicate 3rd party type definitions here to keep clean boundaries.

Without using generics, Typescript wouldn't compile the code below because some of the fields in gridProps would be treated as `any`. Using generics, Typescript is able to match the values with the types expected by the library.

Example (to work with AG Grid):

```html
<!-- grid.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
    type T = $$Generic;
    interface $$Props {
        options: GridOptions<T>;
    }

    export let gridOptions: GridOptions<T>;
</script>

<!-- component.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
    import Grid from './grid.svelte';
    import type { ComponentProps } from 'svelte';

    let rowData = [
        // insert your data here
    ];

    type T = typeof rowData[number];
    const gridProps: ComponentProps<Grid<T>> = {
        gridOptions: {
            // type infer now works
        }
    };
</script>

<Grid {...gridProps} />
```